# Track external file content changes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsfilecoordinator, nsfilepresenter

I've fully implemented the `NSFilePresenter` protocol using `NSFileCoordinator` to track external changes made to an imported folder/file tree. And it generally works.

However, I'm still a bit confused.

- I've implemented almost all (if not all) of the protocol's functions.
- `presentedSubitemDidChangeAtURL:`, `presentedSubitemAtURL:didMoveToURL:` and `presentedItemDidChange` are the only ones getting called
- I am able to successfully track new folders being added, or files moving. However when going to track file **content** changes (edited and saved by another app) things get a bit complicated: The method to be called is `presentedItemDidChange` (which gets obviously called in other cases as well)

What am I missing?

Shouldn't either `presentedItemDidGainVersion:` or `savePresentedItemChangesWithCompletionHandler:` get called?

Any help or pointers are more than welcome! :)

Comment: did you ever find a fix for this?